# Trying to create a Calculated Field - Getting an error. Double checked spelling etc

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

```
 =Department Name&" - "&Title&" - "&Department Team&" - "&Department Branch
```

I am trying to create a calculated column from the following existing columns:

1. Department Name
2. Title (Renamed in list to sub-deparment)
3. Department Team
4. Department Branch

Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Columns with spaces or symbols need to be enclosed in square brackets:

```
=[Department Name] & " - " & [Title] & " - " & [Department Team] & " - " & [Department Branch]
```

I added extra spaces for clarity. While "Title" does not require the brackets as there are no spaces, they do no harm and make it clear this is a column reference.

Comment: Mike, thank your so much! I was banging my head on this one. IT WORKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try using below formula, it should work:

```
=[Department Name]&" - "&[Title]&" - "&[Department Team]&" - "&[Department Branch]
```

Also, you can use **CONCATENATE** function instead of **&**, like below:

```
CONCATENATE([Department Name]," - ",[Title]," - ",[Department Team]," - ",[Department Branch])
```

**Reference**:

[CONCATENATE function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/concatenate-function-5b0392b2-94ef-49ea-8532-4fdd3a69d362)